# Sorting on Multiple fields -- Its working, but not able to understand how is it working

Tags: java, collections

```
class Employee implements Comparable{
    private String name;
        private String gender;

        Employee(String name, String gender) {
            this.name = name;
            this.gender = gender;
        }

        public String getName() {
                return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getGender() {
                return gender;
        }

        public void setGender(String gender) {
                this.gender = gender;
        }
    
        public String toString() {
            return this.getName() + " : " + this.getGender();
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            int gendarComp=this.getGender().compareTo(((Employee)o).getGender());
            return (gendarComp!=0?gendarComp:this.name.compareTo(((Employee)o).getName()));
        }
    } 

    class EmployeeExec {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List allEmpls = new ArrayList();
            allEmpls.add(new Employee("vijay", "m"));
            allEmpls.add(new Employee("balaji", "m"));
            allEmpls.add(new Employee("shaifali", "f"));
            allEmpls.add(new Employee("archana", "f"));
            allEmpls.add(new Employee("alala", "m"));
            allEmpls.add(new Employee("kiran", "f"));

            sortEmployees(allEmpls);
        }

        public static void sortEmployees(List allEmpls) {
            Collections.sort(allEmpls);
            System.out.println(allEmpls);
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me in understanding how it is working? what is the funda to sort? I kept some println statements to see, but I don't really understand how it is getting called. I know its working with merge sort. But how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting is based on the return value of `compareTo` (slightly reformatted for readability):

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int gendarComp = this.getGender().compareTo(((Employee)o).getGender());
    return (gendarComp != 0
               ? gendarComp
               : this.name.compareTo( ((Employee)o).getName() )
           );
}
```

The logic is apparently to compare values of `getGender()` and return that comparison unless they test equal. If they are equal, it returns the result of comparing names.

As an aside: If this is your code, it would be better to use generics instead of raw types. Declare

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {...
```

Then declare the `compareTo` method with the signature:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Employee o) {...
```

and you can dispense with the casts inside the method (as well as improve type safety in client code).

Answer (score 1):

```
 @Override
 public int compareTo(Object o) {
    int gendarComp=this.getGender().compareTo(((Employee)o).getGender());
    return (gendarComp!=0 ?
                            gendarComp
                          : this.name.compareTo(((Employee)o).getName()));
 }
```

As you can see, the code first compares the gender.

If the gender are equal, then the resulting integer will be 0, and then it compares by name as the secondary sort key.

Answer (score 0):

Two people already explained what the compareTo() method does, but since you said

> but I dont really understand how it is getting called

I'll explain that part. When Collections.sort(allEmpls) is called, all of the list objects' compareTo() methods are called against each others', since they all implement the Comparable interface. The code within the sort() method then reorgs the objects based on their compareTo() values. And that's about it (overly simplified, of course, but it answers your question).